# Visualforce page in Standard Page Layout Opening Links in Iframe

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF related list embedded in a STD page layout.  when the user clicks on a record in the rleated list, the vf part navigates to the new page. Obviously, i want the parent to

```
 <apex:page standardController="MyMasterObject__c">
      <apex:relatedList list="MyChildObjects__r" />
 </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one solution is to create a new formula field (type - Text) on the `MyChildObject__c` object that opens the same record but in a new window/tab. And then add this field to the related list on the custom object page at the "Search Layouts" - "Tab":

```
HYPERLINK(Id, Name)
```